# can't print values inside of the property list c#

Tags: c#

I have a game that ask user to guess the price of the item 
after user guesses console has to print all the previous guesses. 
here is my list property

```
private List<Product> _previousGuesses = new List<Product>();
public List<Product> PreviousGuesses {
    get { return _previousGuesses; }
    set { _previousGuesses = value; } 
}
```

and my method that return result:

```
public GuessStatus CheckGuess(int guess)
        {

            if (_randomProduct.Price == guess)
            {
                return GuessStatus.Correct;

            }
            else if (_randomProduct.Price > guess)
            {
                _numberOfTries++;

                newProduct = new Product()
                {
                    Price = guess,
                    Description = _randomProduct.Description
                };
                _previousGuesses.Add(newProduct);

                return GuessStatus.TooLow;
            }
            else
```

and my main program where I am trying to print :

```
case GuessStatus.Correct:
               Console.WriteLine("You got it!");

              Console.WriteLine("Number of tries: " +      game.NumberOfTries);
            List<Product> guessedProducts = game.PreviousGuesses;

        guessedProducts.ForEach(el => Console.WriteLine(el));
```

when I am printing I don't see the prices and descriptions that I guesses, I see project name.classname.Program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here `guessedProducts.ForEach(el => Console.WriteLine(el));` is essentially the following:

```
foreach (var p in guessedProducts)
{
    Console.Write(p.ToString() + "\r\n");
}
```

As you can see, underneath `ToString()` is called on each of your `Products`. However, because `Product` does not have an implementation of `ToString()` the runtime calls `Object.ToString(p)` which essentially returns `p.GetType().Name`.

How to fix this: create an `override ToString(){}` method in your `Product` (start typing "override " and Intellisense will help). There you can present the way you wish your `Product` to be outputted, e.g.:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"Product: {Description}, your guess: {Price}";
}
```

This is just one of numerous ways, but perhaps the easiest so far.

P.S.: you can simplify the expression in question to `guessedProducts.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly was I was looking for.